# R help- creating a sub-data set

Tags: r, subset

I have a large dataset (38053 rows= transcripts, 39 columns=samples)
I want to make a new dataset with all the sample values for a certain group of the transcripts.

```
x= data1["698568366",]
```

works for a single transcript, where "698568366" is the name of the transcript

but now instead of one at a time, I want to use a lits of 3000

I thought I should be able to use:

```
data1[data1[,1] %in% 3000_m,]
```

where 3000_m is the list in matrix form,

but I keep getting back

```
  <0 Rows> (or row.names mit Length 0)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Try `data1[data1[,1] %in% c(3000_m),]` (not tested)

Comment: data1[! data1[,1] %in% 3000_m,]

Comment: `3000_m` is an invalid object name. As stated, please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Here are arrays a and b:

```
a = c(1:10)
b = c(11:20)
```

Creating a dataframe with them:

```
df = data.frame(a, b)
```

Here is my index as an array:

```
ind = c(3, 5, 7)
```

Select rows indexed as ind:

```
new_df = df[ind,]
```

You can't use multidimensional arrays as index (as far as i know).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your transcripts names are actually not stored in the first column of your data frame, but as the row names.

If it is the case and if the names of your transcripts of interest are stored in a vector `myTranscripts`, you could use:

```
x = data1[row.names(data1) %in% myTranscripts, ]
```